# couldn't connect to ElasticSearch inside GetCandy

Tags: laravel, api, elasticsearch, getcandy

As am following the documentation in the site here https://getcandy.io/docs/master/guides/introduction/01-installation

but when got to point to set this code:

> php artisan candy:search:index

having exception error listed here:

```
   Elastica\Exception\Connection\HttpException  : Couldn't connect to host, Elasticsearch down?
```

Comment: Check your configuration settings, to understand what host are configured for elasticsearch connection.

Comment: can you tell me how u  have fixed this issue, i am getting same issue even though my elastic search up and running ?

Comment: you need to read more about elasticsearch so you can figure this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds most likely that Elasticsearch isn't running properly, rather than an issue with GetCandy.

If you run the following you should be able to determine if Elasticsearch is up.

```
curl localhost:9200
```

If you get a response with the Elasticsearch version etc, it is running. If it's not running, you'll need to check the Elasticsearch logs, normally found somewhere like `/var/log/elasticsearch/`

Comment: fixed the Elasticsearch to be up but now it throw another error

   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Call to undefined method Elastica\Index::getType()